# JavaScript Beautifier without line break when using jQuery's css() Method

Tags: javascript, js-beautify

Do you know of any online JavaScript Beautifier that does not format this code

```
$("[id='abc']").css({top: '53px'});
```

like this

```
$("[id='abc']")
    .css({
        top: '53px'
    });
```

but keeps everything on one line?

Answer (score 2):

https://beautifier.io/ with "Preserve inline braces/code blocks?" ticked works.